# The query that i have tried was wrong anyone can give me correct query?

Tags: sql

Age column is not in table `passenger`. Display the name and date of birth of passengers who are senior citizens where (age >= 60) and I have used

**Query:**

```
select 
    passname,
    (extract(year from current_date) - extract(year from passdob)) >60
from 
    passenger
```

Comment: Could you post SQL query, that you have already tried?

Comment: You're just comparing years now, missing the date parts. Subtract the dates, not the years.

Comment: What kind of database are you using? Is it MySQL or something different?

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
SELECT passname, passdob
FROM passenger
WHERE (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM current_date)-EXTRACT(YEAR FROM passdob)) >60
```

Comment: But you need to compare the date parts too, not just the years. (Consider December born people...)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
 SELECT passname, passdob FROM passenger WHERE (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM
 now())-EXTRACT(YEAR FROM passdob)) >60
```

Comment: But you need to compare the date parts too, not just the years. (Consider December born people...)

Comment: Then try to use EXTRACT(MONTH FROM passdob) and EXTRACT(MONTH FROM
 now()) in your condition

Comment: I'm not the one asking the question... And I'm not sure OP undestands what the problem either...